# Symfony2 controller navbar

Tags: php, symfony, controller, twig, navbar

i would put a controller for my navbar and i would use a query to get a variable from my database..
I don't have a controller and i create it in this way:

```
<?php

  namespace Dt\EcBundle\Controller;

  use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
  use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

  class NavbarController extends Controller {

public function navbarAction(Request $request) {
    $prova = "ciao";       
    return $this->render('DtEcBundle:Header:navbar.html.twig',array(
            "prova" => $prova,

    ));
    }
 }
```

Now i put my render controller in the body of : "**{# app/Resources/views/base.html.twig #}**"

```
{{ render(controller('DtEcBundle:Navbar:navbar', { 'prova': prova })) }}
```

I follow this but i don t understand the error: "http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html#embedding-controllers"

I Get this error **Variable "prova" does not exist in DtEcBundle:Header:navbar.html.twig at line 5** but if i write the code in navbar.html.twig give me equals error.. 
If i remove the variable and i write only

```
{{ render(controller('DtEcBundle:Navbar:navbar')) }}
```

Give me a server error number 500 o.o..
How can i do for use my controller only in navbar.html.twig??

Comment: Is `navbar.html.twig` contents something like this : {{ prova }}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92468/discussion-between-scoolnico-and-luca-m).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

navbarAction doesn't take prova variable as a parameter, so why are you passing it there in a base template?

I think that action should fetch these data from db.

In that case, using:

```
{{ render(controller('DtEcBundle:Navbar:navbar')) }}
```

seems to be ok, and error is somewhere else.

If you get a 500, check logs to tell us what's exactly wrong.

And format your code, it's barely readable.

Answer (score 0):

The error is the code:

```
{{ render(controller('DtEcBundle:Navbar:navbar', { 'prova': prova })) }}
```

the prova variable doesn't exists in twig, the controller is fine.
I if you want put the var from twig to controller:

```
 /**
 * @Route("/prova/{prova}", name="prova")
 */
public function navbarAction(Request $request,$prova) {      
    return $this->render('DtEcBundle:Header:navbar.html.twig',array(
            "prova" => $prova,

    ));
}
```

and twig:

```
{% set prova = 'foo' %}
{{ render(controller('DtEcBundle:Navbar:navbar', { 'prova': prova })) }}
```